# React: Specify Location of Nested Children Components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, children

How I want to setup my component hierarchy to be setup like this:

```js
<Page>
  <Page.Section>
     <Page.Item/>
  </Page.Section>
</Page>
```

1. How do I reference the nested children of children components (aka `Page.Item`) to put in a different location because I don't want specific styling to effect it? See Code Comments. Due to the styling, I do not want to change it.
2. How do you only allow `Page.Section` and `Page.Item` to be used in `Page` Component and not standalone?

`Page.js`

```js
const Page = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div
        className='bg-gray-100 border-b-2 flex flex-col top-0 fixed w-screen transition-height duration-300 mt-16'
      >
        <SomeComponent/>
        // Section Children I want here so it takes styling
        {children}
      </div>
        // Item Children I want here so it does not take styling, but I want the Item Children to always be nested in The Page.Section Component.
        {children.children?}
    </>
  );
};

// I want his Section element to be
const Section = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <ConfiguratorTab/>
      {children}
    </>
  );
};

const Item = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Form/>
    </>
  );
};

Page.Section = Section;
Page.Item = Item;

export default Page;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`children` returns an object with the following keys and values.

```
type: ƒ Section() {}
key: null
ref: null
props: Object
_owner: FiberNode
_store: Object
```

The `props` object holds the prop values passed to the current(parent) component. So the children of children component could be accessed using `props`. And since `Item` is a child of `Page` (although not a direct child), you need not include it again in the `Section` component, if you don't want certain styles to be applied to it. This could be accomplished by removing `children` from `Section`.

```
const Section = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <ConfiguratorTab/>
      {//Don't render any children elements here.
      }
    </>
  );
};
```

```
const Page = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div
        className='bg-gray-100 border-b-2 flex flex-col top-0 fixed w-screen transition-height duration-300 mt-16'
      >
        <SomeComponent/>
        // Section Children I want here so it takes styling
        {children}
      </div>
        // Item Children I want here so it does not take styling, but I want the Item Children to always be nested in The Page.Section Component.
        {children.props.children}
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: From the first output of {children}, is there away to filter out so only the first children appear?

Comment: Do you mean only the `section` component should be rendered within the `div` tag excluding the `children` of the `Item` component?

Comment: Or well…excluding `children` of `Item` Component and Section’s `children`. So only `Section` Component should be rendered in `div` And none of its `children`

Comment: I've updated the answer. Please check.

Comment: Nice, is it possible to keep output of of Section component within `div` without its child? Then outside the `div` only output the Item Child? Like this `{React.Children.toArray(children).filter(
            (child) => child.type.name === 'Item'
          )}`  I don’t want Item to have the styling of the div hence I want to separate it out. But Section keeps rendering it’s child (Item). Apologies for confusion.

Comment: If the issue mainly revolves around styling, you'd rather want to apply the styling directly to that particular component without including its children within the scope of styling.